# What is the best known lower bound for: $\max_{2\leq i\leq p-1}(ord_n(i)) $?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

Given an in integer $n$, and let $p$ be its smallest prime divisor (you can assume that $p$ is very large ). Let $ord_n(i)$ denotes the order of $i$ as an element of $\Bbb Z_n^*$ the multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z_n$.

**My question**:

> What is  the best known lower bound for:
>   $$\max_{2\leq i\leq p-1}(ord_n(i)) $$

**A lower bound**

For example it's clear that if $k=ord_n(2)$ then $$2^k>n$$ because $$2^k\equiv 1 \mod n $$

so as a lower bound we have $\log_2(n) \leq \max_{2\leq i\leq p-1}(ord_n(i))$ I'm looking for references which discuss this problem.

Crossposted at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202362

Comment: I assume $p$ is a prime divisor?

Comment: yes it's the smallest prime divisor of $n$